# Substrate Claim Tutorial

Tags: pallet

Following the tutorial for adding Claims Pallet to a Substrate blockchain.

```
    #[pallet::call]
    impl<T: Config> Pallet<T> {
        #[pallet::weight(0)]
        pub fn create_claim(origin: OriginFor<T>, claim: T::Hash, data: BoundedVec<u8, T::MaxStringLength>) -> DispatchResult {
```

We are getting a warning:

```
warning: use of deprecated struct `pallet::warnings::create_claim`:                     Implicit call indices are deprecated in favour of explicit ones.
Please ensure that all calls have the `pallet::call_index` attribute or that the
`dev-mode` of the pallet is enabled. For more info see:
<https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/pull/12891> and
<https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/pull/11381>.
```

not sure how to use the call_index attribute?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add the macro `call_index` in above your extrinsics:

```rs
 #[pallet::call_index(0)]
 #[pallet::weight(0)]
 pub fn create_claim(origin: OriginFor<T>, claim: T::Hash, data: BoundedVec<u8, T::MaxStringLength>) -> DispatchResult {
```

You can see the example in the [pallet_template](https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-node-template/blob/main/pallets/template/src/lib.rs#L66) in the node_template.

And you can read more information about this [Macro in the docs](https://paritytech.github.io/substrate/master/frame_support_procedural/attr.call_index.html).